# Calling function on unlike event of facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook

I have been calling a function to run a query in to the database on a like event of facebook like button on my python site .And it is working absolutely fine .

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget)
```

But the problem is I need to use a another query of update on unlike event of the facebook button.

```
<script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
            top.window.location = 'http://pydev.abc.com/surpriseme/';
        });
    </script>
        <div class="suprise">
            <div class="suprise_con">
                <div class="fb-like"   style="overflow:hidden;" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/VivaAviesta" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
                <span style="margin-left:5px;"> Like Us to Reveal</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For the url surprise me I have added a functionin views :

```
def surpriseme(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT "......." (name,facebook_id,category,user_id) VALUES ('Abcd',1,'',%s)",[request.user.id])
        #return HttpResponse("success")
        return redirect("/showroom/")
```

Can anyone help in calling another function at the unlike event?

Actually the thing is that the person who has not liked the face book button on our site will not be able to see few of the products and once he/she hits like button they can see the products.
Now what I need is if anyone again unlike the button will should not be able to see products , which is not working at the moment.

Comment: hmmm... You know requiring a user to *like* or *share* something to get access to additional content (or entries in competitions) is against the terms, right? It's directly interfering with Zuck's money: advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calll like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit=function() {
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
 top.window.location = '{{baseurl}}/surprisemeunlike/';

});
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
            top.window.location = '{{baseurl}}/surpriseme/';
               var url = '{{baseurl}}/surpriseme/';
            });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer, there is another event fron facebook :

```
FB.Event.unsubscribe('edge.create', handleResponse);
```

We can call another function on this event .

```
<script>
        FB.Event.unsubscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {


            top.window.location = 'http://pydev.abc.com/surpriseunlike/';


        });
    </script>
```

and it is working fine for me now .

Answer (score 0):

"Like Gating" isn't against the terms of service and is used by many brands.  It worked well under FBML, but it isn't reliable for an actual lockdown on the current API options.  Facebook only prohibits requiring a like for contest entries (unless you use an approved vendor to run the contest).

If you actually want to require people to "Like" , you should be using their Graph API and 'realtime updates' https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/   Your javascript function will only work if someone likes or unlikes on that same page.  It won't handle people liking or unliking in other browser windows or different time periods, which undermines your intent.

But if someone Likes your page and then unlikes it - so what?  They already saw your special content.